# jquery: Why is this not working on Chrome?

Tags: jquery

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#enter').click(function() {
    $.post('setCookie.php');
    });     
});
</script> 

<div id="enter"> 
    <a href="http://www.mydomain.com">Enter</a> 
</div>
```

When clicking enter, it is supposed to go to mydomain.com and also set a cookie. It is working in Firefox, but not IE or Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason the .click can't act on the anchor? If not, then you can quickly get around the problem of dealing with jQuery's event ordering.

Comment: Can you direct the link to setCookie.php, then add header('location: http://www.mydomain.com') after it's been set?

Answer (score 2):

It may be going to the site before it loads for Chrome.  You could set a target attribute to "_blank" on the anchor tag, or you could use a callback function after $.post finishes, like so:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
    $('#enter').click(function() {
    $.post('setCookie.php',function(){
window.location = $('#enter a').attr('href');
});
    });     
});
</script> 

<div id="enter"> 
    <a href="http://www.mydomain.com" onclick="return false;">Enter</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed it up a bit, if you want to try again.  It's tough doing cross-browser sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#enter a').click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       var href = this.href;
       $.post('setCookie.php', function(){
          window.location.href = href;
       });
    });     
});
```

Comment: The link just doesn't work, when I click on it, it ignores me. It does not set the cookie either.

Comment: If you have fiddler, can you see if any request is being made when u click?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try with</s>

```
$('#enter a').click(function() {
```

Edit: You have a `POST` going on the anchor click and then a `GET` with the anchor itself. That seams to be clashing on the browser.

For better results, create a `SetCookieAndRedirect.php` page and perform the redirect to the url after setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the .post() call is asynchronous so the rest of the function will continue to flow with the .post() working in the background. You will need to use a callback function inside your post: If you don't want error checking you can skip the if/else and just call the redirect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {

      if (data.success === 'cookieset')
      {
          // redirect to page
              window.location.replace("http://mydomain.com");
      }
      else
      {
          // put some sort of notification here that it wasn't set and decide what to do next
              window.location.replace("http://mydomain.com");
      }

    });
});
```

as far as the redirect you can use either:

to simulate an http redirect use

`window.location.replace("http://mydomain.com")`;

or simulates clicking on a link use

```
window.location.href = "http://mydomain.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do

```
<a href="javascript:$.post('setCookie.php');window.location='http://www.mydomain.com'">abc</a>
```

Comment: I did a little mistake entering my answer, my bad.